# Problems with componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use componentDidMount() to initialize data for a Component by a fetchData actions (Redux). And this component called with different route, such as:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="path1" component={ThisComponent} />
  <Route path="path2" component={ThisComponent} />
</Switch>
```

- The problems is, when come to path2 from path1, I want to change the state => Component re-render => re-call componentDidMount() => initial state, And I cannot change state Of my App. Please help :(

Comment: You may have to use `componentWillReceiveProps` and place logic to fetch data. Switch does not create a new component. So `componentDidMount` wont work from second time on.

Comment: Could you explainer clearer? I write two actions to fetch two diff data, now Im use the first to initialize data in componentDidMount() and call the left one when change the route, state changed at reducers and as I know, my prop has to change, but it not